# Percona cluster not running in cluster mode

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, percona

I'm setting up a percona cluster (ver 5.6) on CentOS 6.5 in AWS ec2 according to the official guide:
[How to setup 3 node cluster in EC2 enviroment](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.6/howtos/3nodesec2.html)

When I run this command on the first node:

> /etc/init.d/mysql bootstrap-pxc

or

> service mysql bootstrap-pxc

The output on my console is

> Starting MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster).. SUCCESS!

Not the output from the guide:

> 2014-01-30 11:52:35 23280 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
>
> Version: '5.6.15-56'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release 25.3, Revision 706, wsrep_25.3.r4034

Looks like it's running in single server mode, not the cluster mode.

Then I start mysql service on the second node:

> service mysql start

and get this error:

> Starting MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster)...................................... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/mnt/data/ben-ec2-usw1.pid).
>
> ERROR! MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster) server startup failed!

Can anyone help on this? Thanks.

Comment: I did some test on my local VMs and the same settings work! It looks like to be a private/public IP binding issue in EC2.

Comment: Note that all of the servers are located in different AWS datacenters.

Answer (score 0):

You may have misread the guide. This output: `Starting MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster).. SUCCESS!` comes from the `service` command. This output:

> 2014-01-30 11:52:35 23280 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
>
> Version: '5.6.15-56' socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' port: 3306
>   Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release 25.3, Revision 706, wsrep_25.3.r4034

comes from a `tail` of the mysql error log file.

On your second node, did you examine the error log for the failure reason? Did you correctly configure `gcomm://` URI in the my.cnf of node2? Did you open all necessary ports in the AWS security groups?